# change *.foo to *.bar in unix one-liner

Tags: linux, unix, shell, command-line, cp

I am trying to convert all files in a given directory with suffix ".foo" to files containing the same basename but with suffix modified to ".bar". I am able to do this with a shell script and a for loop, but I want to write a one-liner that will achieve the same goal.

Objective:
  Input: *.foo
  Output: *.bar

This is what I have tried:

```
find . -name "*.foo" | xargs -I {} mv {} `basename {} ".foo"`.bar
```

This is close but incorrect. Results:
  Input: *.foo
  Output: *.foo.bar

Any ideas on why the given suffix is not being recognized by basename? The quotes around ".foo" are dispensable and the results are the same if they are omitted.

Comment: There MUST be a way to do this using `find`'s `-exec`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although `basename` can work on file extensions, using the shell parameter expansion features is easier:

```
for file in *.foo; do mv "$file" "${file%.foo}.bar"; done
```

Your code with `basename` doesn't work because the `basename` is only run once, and then xargs just sees `{}.bar` each time.

Comment: in csh you can use `$file:r.bar`  to change the foo to bar

Answer (score 2):

> for file in *.foo ; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)foo/\1bar/'` ; done

Example:

```
$ ls
1.foo  2.foo
$ for file in *.foo ; do mv $file `echo $file | sed 's/\(.*\.\)foo/\1bar/'` ; done
$ ls
1.bar  2.bar
$
```

Comment: Might be best to anchor that match with a $ lest you catch files with 'foo' in their name.  's/\.foo$/\.bar/'

Comment: This one wont do anything to file named `foo`; which is what OP wants I believe.

Comment: Yep, you're right, of course.  I wasn't thinking about the .* being greedy.

Comment: In any case, this is my preference as it's shell independent.  Not that you're going to see super old-school sh in the wild these days, but if you ever find yourself on a SunOS 4 box and you notice the lack of shell parameter expansion, knowing sed is always a plus.

Answer (score 1):

for x in $(find . -name "*.foo"); do mv $x ${x%%foo}bar; done

Comment: WIll break with file names containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ for f in *.foo; do echo mv $f ${f%foo}bar; done
mv a.foo a.bar
mv b.foo b.bar
```

Remove `echo` when ready.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed `mmv`, you can do

```
mmv \*.foo \#1.bar
```

.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use "rename" instead of scripts or loops.

RHEL: `rename foo bar .*foo`

Debian: `rename 's/foo/bar/' *.foo`